# VBS/HTML Can't get InputBox to pop up

Tags: html, vbscript

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/vbscript">
Function sub()
Ms=MsgBox(UN, 1)
End Function
</script>

Username: <input
 id="UN"
 type=text>
 <br/>

Password: <input
 name="PW"
 type=password>
 <br/>

<input
 name="Submit"
 type=submit
 onclick="sub()">

</body>
</html>
```

When the submit button is pressed, the function doesn't show the MsgBox at all. Let alone the username..

Comment: No, I am using a w3schools tryit editor, http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro and then copy and pasting the code back and forth.

Comment: Why are you trying to use VBScript instead of Javascript?

Comment: I'm not that great with other languages -- Lua, VBScript and HTML are the only ones I understand.

Comment: Do yourself a favour, don’t use VBS in HTML. Buy a modern book and learn JavaScript. It’s easy. VBS has absolutely *no* future in HTML. No modern browser supports it; the only browser to ever have supported it is now in the absolute minority and cannot be considered modern.

Comment: Well, you're greatly, greatly limiting yourself with VBScript. I strongly recommend learning Javascript, it's not that difficult. It even allows you to do white-space delimited coding.

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11246/best-resources-to-learn-javascript

Comment: I know VBS isn't all that great, it's actually really bad come to think of it, I'm only doing this for testing.

Answer (score 0):

You are using a reserved word, just change `Function sub()` to something like `Function mySub()` and it will work.

If you want the value, then you need to do `Ms=MsgBox(UN.value, 1)` instead of `Ms=MsgBox(UN, 1)`

Comment: Make sure you change the name in the onclick event of the submit button to match the new name of your function.

Comment: Thanks! I got it! The problem was Google Chrome thinks VBS is used for XSS, so I just used IE